# Collection view cell layout

Tags: ios, swift

Hi guys I am trying to create a AirBnB app lookalike horizontal scrolling. Everything is going great so far but I am walking into some issues. I try to make every 3rd item bigger. Somehow tho hey don't resize. see the screenshot below

The third item has nothing under it but it doesn't resize. to the full height. Instead it messes the whole layout.

[image: What I am getting]

How it should be is

[image]

Here is what I do

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if indexPath.item % 3 == 0 && indexPath.item != 0 {
        return CGSizeMake(420, 520)
    }

    return CGSizeMake(420, 260)
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

A cells size is set by the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout method

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                      layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
      sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
```

For example:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                      layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
      sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize{

    if indexPath.item % 3 == 0 && indexPath.item != 0 {
        return CGSize(400,1200)
    }
    return CGSize(400,600)
}
```

Comment: Yes, I figured that out from the docs and adapted. But its still not matching my needs see my updated example of how it should be.

Comment: Why did you ask that question then?

Comment: Seems like you cell is not layed out correctly. Are you still setting it's frame? If you are, try deleting that.

Comment: No I am not setting the frame. Only thing I do is what you have suggested. ( see my example code ) and I modified the question after I figured it out :) my bad

Answer (score 0):

I think you are counting your cells wrong if you want it like in the photo you should say:

```
if (indexPath.item + 1) % 3 == 0 && indexPath.item != 0 {
        return CGSizeMake(420, 520)
    }
```

[image]